# how much its feasible to add reference EXE instead of dll

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

a project which is completed in visual studio 2010 (vb.net) 3.5 .net name : fieldManager

i want to embed above project in my another application which i will be developing in 
 same visual studio 2010 (vb.net) 3.5 .net name : expressionEditor

my question is how much its feasible to add reference EXE instead of dll
 i.e instead of converting fieldManager project into class library and adding reference 
  will there be any issues if i directly add reference EXE of 
 fieldManager project to expressionEditor

please help!

Comment: @hans-passant:  i wasnt satisfied by the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely feasible - it used not to be supported within the "Add reference" dialog, but that was back in the VS2002/2003 days - I believe it's been fully supported since VS2005.

You might consider whether it would be *better* to break out common aspects into a separate library that both apps can use, admittedly... but you absolutely *can* refer to one exe-based assembly from another (or even from a class library).

As a side note, project names are normally PascalCased in .NET, e.g. FieldManager and ExpressionEditor, rather than fieldManager and expressionEditor. As Visual Studio bases its default namespaces on the project name, this can be fairly significant.

Comment: one more doubt does adding exe will affect memory usage?

Comment: @Dandy: No more than a DLL, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: thank you very much and thanx a ton for PasCalCase